# Attemping to store a html input value into a php variable

Tags: php, html

```
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input style='position: relative; top: 20px; left: 20px;' class='autotext' id="aaaa" type="text" name="myInput" placeholder="Insert Name Here" value="<?php echo $var; ?>" />
  </div>
  <input style='position: relative; top:20px; left: 30px' class='submitButton' type="submit">
</form>

    <?php
    $var = $_POST['myInput'];
    ?>
```

I am attempting to develop an `<input>` field where the value of said field is replaced with the value of a php variable that stored the previous value of that field, preferably I'd like to simply be able to retain the user-input value after the post whilst being able to run a MySQL query on the stored php var. I'm not sure how to achieve this as the 'value' field of the `<input>` simply displays the string `'<?php echo $var ?>'` I essentially want it to display its placeholder until `$var` has a value and then retain the `$var` value whilst replacing the placeholder with the `$var`.
Hopefully my explanation makes sense :/

Comment: _“as the 'value' field of the `<input>` simply displays the string `'<?php echo $var ?>'`”_ - that very clearly indicates, that the whole thing was not parsed as PHP in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the input data from the form stored in the values, if something in the form isn't filled in, or filled in correctly right?

So create your form like you do normaly, and send it to the same page.

```
<form action="thispage.php" method="POST">
<input name="username" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['username'])){ echo $_POST['username'] }"?> >
<button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Now u got a form that will set the value of the input the user filled in. You can extend this with php to create a variable that will count the empty fields, if all the fields are filled in correctly execute the function u want to do next.

I hope this helped u out

Comment: the isset function will look if you created the variable, if you didn't it won't run the script. If you wanna look if a variable is empty use the empty() function from php. 

if u need more help let me know, if i misunderstood your question, please explain a bit more of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to do as you said Jazzly
However it is still failing to parse the statement through PHP
It is fairly adamant as reading it as a string

Currently the code looks like this

```
<form action='Home.html' autocomplete="off" method='POST'>
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input style='position: relative; top: 20px; left: 20px;' class='autotext' id="eeee" type="text" name="myInput" placeholder="aaaaa" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['myInput'])) { echo $_POST['myInput']; } ?>" >
  </div>
<input style='position: relative; top:20px; left: 30px' class='submitButton' type="submit">
</form>
```

The output is as follows:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['myInput'])) { echo $_POST['myInput']; } ?>
```

Could it have something do do with being stored in a html doc as opposed to a pure PHP doc?

Answer (score -1):

Time to answer my own question
The trick to updating the value of a html element with its own previous value (without relogging the page is AJAX jQuery)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
        var name = $('#myInput').val()
        $.post('validate.php', {postname:name}, 
            function(data) {
                $('#newText').html(data);
                $('#AJAX').val(data); 
            }); 
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<!--Make sure the form has the autocomplete function switched off:-->
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <div id="AJAX">
        <input style="position: relative; top: 20px; left: 20px" class="autotext" id="myInput" type="text" name="aaaaa" placeholder="placeholder">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button style="position: relative; top:20px; left: 30px" class="submitButton" id="button">Submit</button>
  <div style="position: absolute; top: 100px" id="newText">
  
  </div>

<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The following code resolves the issue as a jQuery post won't relog the page
However you may notice that in the script I am posting to 'validate.php'
That is simply a basic php document with the two following lines of code

```
<?php
$var = $_POST['postname'];
echo $var;
?>
```

Then the line `$(#'AJAX').val(data);` is responsible for updating the value however this line is not technically needed to be used on its own input box as posting via jQuery does not refresh and retains the value that was posted
Yet I included that line anyway for anyone else to reference how to update the value of other html elements

I hope my explanation makes sense
I went on a journey trying to figure it out lol
The line above it was simply testing updating the value of a `<div>` element
Also ignore the autocomplete div as it isn't part of the solution to this problem